# PHP Remove middle section of a string

Tags: php, regex

I have a url that will always look like some variation of this

```
https://sitename/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/59a778097ae6e-150x150.jpeg
```

I need to remove with PHP the resolution specifier "-150x150" so that it reads

```
https://sitename/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/59a778097ae6e.jpeg
```

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Is the `-` a separate or a negative integer? Maybe replace `-\d+x\d+` with nothing, or if negative `-?\d+x-?\d+`.

Comment: `(-\d+x\d+)(?=\.)`?

Comment: This question should be closed as Needs Clarity because we don't know if `-150x150` is a static string or if the dimensions in the needle string are dynamic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's always `-150x150` you can just use `str_replace()`:

```
$url = "https://sitename/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/59a778097ae6e-150x150.jpeg";
$stripped = str_replace('-150x150', '', $url);
var_dump($stripped);
// string(62) "https://sitename/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/59a778097ae6e.jpeg"
```

If you need a way to strip out *any* resolution, you can use a regular expression for that:

```
$url = "https://sitename/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/59a778097ae6e-150x150.jpeg";
$stripped = preg_replace('/-[0-9]+x[0-9]+/', '', $url);
var_dump($stripped);
// string(62) "https://sitename/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/59a778097ae6e.jpeg"
```

Answer (score 1):

hello you can use `strpos()` and `substr()` functions

```
<?php

$str1 =  "https://sitename/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/59a778097ae6e-150x150.jpeg";
$str2   = "-150x150";

$pos = strpos($str1, $str2);

$part1 = substr($str1, $pos); 
$part2 = substr($pos+1, strlen($str1)); 

$final_str = $part1.$part2;
echo $final_str;


?>
```

or you can also just use `str_replace()` and replace the part of the url by nothing :

```
<?php

$url = "https://sitename/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/59a778097ae6e-150x150.jpeg";
$str = "-150x150";

// will replace $str by '' in $url
$url = str_replace($str, '', $url);
echo $url;

?>
```

Comment: Why not just use `str_replace()`?

Answer (score 0):

If it's not always 150x150, here's a nifty solution.

```
    $url = 'https://sitename/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/59a778097ae6e-150x150.jpeg';
```

First get the extension

```
    $ext = explode('.', $url);
    $ext = $ext[count($ext)-1];
```

Then split by '-'

```
    $array = explode('-', $url);
```

Pop the last array element which will be the resolution (150x150 here)

```
    array_pop($array);
```

Then implode by '-' again and concatenate the extension to the new url

```
    $new_url = implode('-', $array). '.' .$ext;
```